# SQL Server: get median value

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, median

How can i get the median value of each one of grouped values of a collumn from a select statement. I guess i use Row number but not sure how to go about it.

Note: if even number just take either middle no.

```
name size
joe 10
joe 11
joe 19
joe 20
joe 47
sally 3
sally 8
sally 57
john 1
john 3
```

I want to get Joe 19, Sally 8, John 3

Answer (score 0):

Set up testing data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Foo (Name varchar(10), value int)

INSERT #Foo values
  ('joe', 10)
 ,('joe', 11)
 ,('joe', 19)
 ,('joe', 20)
 ,('joe', 47)
 ,('sally', 3)
 ,('sally', 8)
 ,('sally', 57)
 ,('john', 1)
 ,('john', 3)
```

First pass, get proper ordering:

```
SELECT Name, Value, row_number() over (partition by name order by value) ranking
 from #Foo
```

Second pass, identify median item (If even number of items, the "first" item found is always returned)

```
;WITH cteRankings (Name, Value, Ranking)
 as (select Name, Value, row_number() over (partition by name order by value) ranking
      from #Foo)
SELECT Name, avg(Ranking) MedianItem
 from cteRankings
 group by Name
```

Final pass, get the details for the median item:

```
;WITH cteRankings (Name, Value, Ranking)
 as (select Name, Value, row_number() over (partition by name order by value) Ranking
      from #Foo)
SELECT cte.Name, cte.Value
  from cteRankings cte
   inner join (--  Median items
               select Name, avg(Ranking) MedianItem
                from cteRankings
                group by Name) xx
    on xx.Name = cte.Name
     and xx.MedianItem = cte.Ranking
 order by cte.Name
```

Done as a cte (common table expression), because a subquery was called for and needed to be referenced twice.